# Hey all, i need solution to this problem on Facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I have a very weird problem with a Facebook group,  where I am the admin. Everything was alright,  until 2 days ago I haven't been able to make new posts. When I click on make new post , nothing happens,except the screen gets refreshed. I made another member an admin and they faced the same problem too . However when I removed myself as admin ,I was able to write a new post and submit for admin approval.

This is so strange that admins cant make a new post but a normal member can .

Please help me with solutions to solve this problem.Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

P.s. the other member can't stay admin for long.

Answer (score 0):

Tried finding a solution to your specific problem without success.

I would suggest you contact facebook help center regarding this.

> 1. Log into Facebook on a computer.
> 2. Click your profile picture in the top right of Facebook.
> 3. Select Help & support, then select Report a problem and follow the on-screen instructions.

[Facebook help center instructions](https://www.facebook.com/help/1075368719167893?locale=en_US&cms_id=1075368719167893&published_only=true)